# Subtract days from a DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

I have the following code in my C# program.

```
DateTime dateForButton =  DateTime.Now;  
dateForButton = dateForButton.AddDays(-1);  // ERROR: un-representable DateTime
```

Whenever I run it, I get the following error:

> *The added or subtracted value results in an un-representable DateTime.*
>   *Parameter name: value*

Iv'e never seen this error message before, and don't understand why I'm seeing it.  From the answers Iv'e read so far, I'm lead to believe that I can use -1 in an add operation to subtract days, but as my question shows this is not the case for what I'm attempting to do.

Comment: Should work , is this the problem area ?

Comment: Nothing is wrong. Do you get an exception? On which line?

Comment: it **has** to work, don't see any problem with this...

Comment: full error text: The added or subtracted value results in an un-representable DateTime. Parameter name: value

Comment: That error usually occurs when you try to subtract an interval from `DateTime.MinValue` or you want to add something to `DateTime.MaxValue` (or you try to instantiate a date outside this min-max interval). Are you sure you're not assigning `MinValue` somewhere?

Comment: CyberDude, your comment is in fact Answer. How can I vote on your Comment and Assign it as Answer?

Comment: Does "dateForButton -= TimeSpan.FromDays(1)" work?

Comment: @CyberDude He is using `DateTime.Now`. And in his comment I can see it returns 22-6. Therefore he is not using Min or Max date.

Comment: There, I posted as an answer :)

Comment: @Aphelion Yes, if that were the only code he has but I suspect there is more between the declaration and the AddDays call. In that part I guess the value is changing.

Comment: Please post the code between lines 2 and 3 of your code

Comment: @CyberDude Nice thought. Voted your answer up.

Comment: There is nothing wrong. This code runs fine. Try and clean the solution and rebuild before testing again.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

That error usually occurs when you try to subtract an interval from `DateTime.MinValue` or you want to add something to `DateTime.MaxValue` (or you try to instantiate a date outside this min-max interval). Are you sure you're not assigning `MinValue` somewhere?

Answer (score 421):

```
DateTime dateForButton = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
```

Comment: This answer, answer the topic title. This never should be downvoted. Most of people come here from google. If someone don't agree with this answer should offer an edit on topic title. ¬¬

Comment: Worked for me even across months.

Answer (score 56):

You can do:

```
DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1)
```

Answer (score 52):

You can use the following code:

```
dateForButton = dateForButton.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(1));
```

Comment: This will also fail if the date is DateTime.MinValue. AddDays(-1) works just as well

Answer (score 15):

The `dateTime.AddDays(-1)`   does not subtract that one day from the `dateTime` reference. It will return a new instance, with that one day subtracted from the original reference.

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;
DateTime otherDateTime = dateTime.AddDays(-1);
```

Comment: Care to explain how this would solve the OP's problem? Almost anyone can write code, that's the easy part. (However, in this case, I actually don't see how this would solve the OP's problem at all.)

Answer (score 9):

Instead of directly decreasing number of days from the date object directly, first get date value then subtract days. See below example:

```
DateTime SevenDaysFromEndDate = someDate.Value.AddDays(-1);
```

Here, someDate is a variable of type DateTime.

Answer (score 6):

The object (i.e. destination variable) for the AddDays method can't be the same as the source.

Instead of:

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
today.AddDays(-7);
```

Try this instead:

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
DateTime sevenDaysEarlier = today.AddDays(-7);
```

Comment: This answer does not really bring a new point if we are looking to the other existing answers.

Answer (score 6):

I've had issues using *AddDays(-1)*.

My solution is **TimeSpan**.

```
DateTime.Now - TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
```

Comment: What was your exact issue ?

Answer (score -1):

Using `AddDays(-1)` worked for me until I tried to cross months. When I tried to subtract 2 days from 2017-01-01 the result was 2016-00-30. It could not handle the month change correctly (though the year seemed to be fine).

I used `date = Convert.ToDateTime(date).Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(2)).ToString("yyyy-mm-dd");`
and have no issues.

Comment: This answer appears to be incorrect. See the example here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/a0xmc5

Comment: mm uses minutes, MM is the numeric month