# Subtract days from the DateTime format

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

```
DateTime followingTrialDate = Convert.ToDateTime(row["FollowingTrialDate"]);
if (followingTrialDate.AddDays(-14))
{
  ModuleBody = davaTarih.ToShortDateString() + " tarihli dava'ya 14 (on dört) gün kalmıştır.";
  ModuleBody = "sayın ilgili, \r\n \r\n" + "esas no: " + esasNo + "\r\n" + "dava tarihi: " + davaTarih.ToShortDateString() + "\r\n" + "sonraki duruşma tarihi: " + sonrakidurusmaTar + "\r\n" + "kısa açıklama: " + kısaAciklama + "\r\n\r\n" + "bilginize,";
}
```

It gives an error in the "if" cycle. Error:

> Cannot implicitly Convert Type 'System.DateTime' to 'bool'

I know the error, the "if" loop gets bool value. But I could not get a date from
the DateTime type. How to subtract from DateTime type 14 days ?

Comment: What do you want to check in your if condition?

Comment: `if (followingTrialDate == followingTrialDate.AddDays(-14))`, is this enough? As general rule, if condition must use `bool` or expression which returns `bool`.

Comment: an `if` must evaluate something to true or false in order to decide whether to go into the if block or not. The result of `DateTime.addDays` is another `DateTime` object. You can't interpret a `DateTime` as being true or false. Your if statement does not make any sense. In English your if statement reads as "If trialDate minus 14 days". It's incomplete and nonsensical. Did you mean to compare it to some other date, maybe the current date?

Comment: Your if condition does not make sense even in natural language: if following trial date minus 14 days... What?

Comment: I mean, 19.07.2017 - 14 Days = 05.07.2017 should be this way. 
How can I write this in the "if" loop?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to subtract a day from a DateTime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11151976/how-to-subtract-a-day-from-a-datetime)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're subtracting the days fine. `followingTrialDate.AddDays(-14)` is correct, it returns the `followingTrialDate` minus the 14 days (as a new `DateTime`). The issue is you've not got any comparison in the if statement:

> Can not implicitly Convert Type 'System.DateTime' to 'bool'

Describes the problem exactly. Your code is similar to:

```
if (new DateTime()) {
    // do something
}
```

Which produces the exact same error. If the date time what? It cannot be `true` or `false`. `If` only operates on a boolean.

I suspect you want to compare it to some other date time with `>` or `<`.

This would work, for example:

```
if (followingTrialDate.AddDays(-14) < DateTime.Now)
```

Answer (score 3):

you have an error in if statement. Function AddDays returns DateTime ([link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays(v=vs.110).aspx)) and **not** bool.

If you want to subtract days, you are on the correct path:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2017, 7, 20);
dt = dt.AddDays(-5);
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString()); // output: 15. 07. 2017
```

Answer (score 1):

> Cannot implicitly Convert Type 'System.DateTime' to 'bool'

The [DateTime.AddDays](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays(v=vs.110).aspx) method Returns a new DateTime that adds the specified number of days to the value of this instance. Whereas `if` expect a condition that  evaluates to a boolean value. this mismatch leads to the above specified error.

> how to subtract from DateTime type 14 days ?

For this you have to assign the result of `AddDays()` to a DateTime variable like the following:

```
DateTime PrevDate = followingTrialDate.AddDays(-14);
// Proceed with PrevDate
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime followingTrialDate = Convert.ToDateTime(row["FollowingTrialDate"]).AddDays(-14);
```

will do the trick. You might want to do some error handling here, though (what if `row["FollowingTrialDate"]` cannot be converted to DateTime and thus throws an exception?).

The only problem that remains is what you want to check in your `if`-condition.

Answer (score 0):

An `if` statement must a boolean expression - a date is not a boolean expression

Instead as you are getting your Date from a DataRow and it may be null why not try something like this, which will check if the row is null and if not then calculate 14 days before the date.

```
if (row["FollowingTrialDate"] != null)
{
    DateTime followingTrialDate = Convert.ToDateTime(row["FollowingTrialDate"]);
    followingTrialDate = followingTrialDate.AddDays(-14);
    ModuleBody = davaTarih.ToShortDateString() + " tarihli dava'ya 14 (on dört) gün kalmıştır.";
    ModuleBody = "sayın ilgili, \r\n \r\n" + "esas no: " + esasNo + "\r\n" + "dava tarihi: " + davaTarih.ToShortDateString() + "\r\n" + "sonraki duruşma tarihi: " + sonrakidurusmaTar + "\r\n" + "kısa açıklama: " + kısaAciklama + "\r\n\r\n" + "bilginize,";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here we've another way to subtract days from DateTime**

```
DateTime oldDt = dt.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(14));
```

`row["FollowingTrialDate"]` should be parsed to `DateTime` for comparison.
e.g., format is `mm/dd/yyyy`

You can handle it like this:

```
if(row["FollowingTrialDate"]!=null
{
   DateTime dt=DateTime.ParseExact(row["FollowingTrialDate"].ToString(),"mm/dd/yyyy");
   if( dt < oldDt ) //or any date comparison you like
   {
      //code here
   }
}
```