How to subtract 1 day when using Datetime
I am attempting to get the number of orders from the last 24 hours from a third party system.
I havent used DatetimeOffset before so eventually figured out how to subtract 1 day from the current day. I then created some dummy records and set their value to yesterday but with the below code it doesnt seem to work (im expecting 3 orders to come through from the 4 as their date is set to yesterday.
ordersTierAmount(DateTimeOffSet.UtcNow);
int ordersTierAmount(DateTimeOffset datetime)
{
    var ts = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0);
    var all = GetAll();
    var count = all.Count(i => i.ConfirmedDateTime == datetime.Subtract(ts));

    return count;
}

List<Order> GetAll()
{
    return new List<Order>
    {
        new Order { Id = "1", ConfirmedDateTime = new DateTimeOffset(new DateTime(2024,06,02)) },
        new Order { Id = "2", ConfirmedDateTime = new DateTimeOffset(new DateTime(2024,06,02)) },
        new Order { Id = "3", ConfirmedDateTime = new DateTimeOffset(new DateTime(2024,06,02)) },
        new Order { Id = "4", ConfirmedDateTime = new DateTimeOffset(new DateTime(2024,06,01)) }
    };
}

public class Order
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset ConfirmedDateTime { get; set; }
}

Where am i going wrong? What have i missed for the correct number of orders not to appear?
I read up on MSDN as i think i did the subtract wrong https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.subtract?view=net-8.0

There's another way to subtract a day from a DateTime/DateTimeOffset https://stackoverflow.com/a/11152156/1043380

If you don't care about Date values across timezones, don't use DateTimeOffset.

The third party system only accepts DateTimeOffSet. When using .AddDays that doesnt work either - i.ConfirmedDateTime == datetime.AddDays(-1)

"From the last 24 hours" and "From yesterday" mean different things nearly all the time. The only moment when the two are aligned is at midnight on any given day. You would do well to conceive datetimes and floating point numbers, where the date is the integer portion and the time is the decimal portion. It would help you mentally model why a datetime of 2024-02-03 12:34:56 is not equal to 2024-02-03, for similar reasons that 1.67485 is not equal to 1. Do not use == when looking for floating point numbers, or dates, in a range. Use ranges built from logic based on > and <

For example, "from yesterday" is >= DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1) and < DateTIme.Today i.e. two dates 24h apart with midnight as their time component, whereas "from the last 24his> DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1) and < DateTime.Nowi.e. two dates 24h apart with the same time component. The.Today` proeprty gives the present datetime, with the time portion set to 00:00:00, something like a "floor" operation would reduce 1.67485 to 1

The problem is that the DateTimeOffset that you're passing to the ordersTierAmount() method has a non-zero Time component, so comparison with the dummy dates (which have no Time component) will return false.
Change this:
var count = all.Count(i => i.ConfirmedDateTime == datetime.Subtract(ts));

to this:
var count = all.Count(i => i.ConfirmedDateTime.Date == datetime.Subtract(ts).Date);

and you should find that you get the result you expect.
(Please note that while this is intended to answer your question, it might not be the behaviour you want.)

That did the trick! However i dont understand the warning you have given (about the behaviour)? What behaviour may occur that i wont want?

Hi Keith - all I meant was that your question says "from the last 24 hours", whereas this code gets all the orders from the previous day (which isn't quite the same thing). If that's what you want, this is probably fine.

To support "last 24h" use > instead of == (and keep the time component, of course)
